# SharePoint 2013 provider-hosted apps without app domain configuration?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

We've got a SharePoint 2013 farm, where we won't be able to get a wildcard certificate for the app domain (corporate regulations).

As we only want to develop provider-hosted apps (mainly ASP.NET MVC and MVC Web API), the question came up, if it is possible to set up SharePoint in a way that we can develop (high-trust) provider-hosted apps, without configuring the app domain part of the farm and still use https for SharePoint and the apps.

I think it should be possible, because I already successfully tested our provider-hosted apps after clearing the app domain setting in the CA and removing the DNS entry (e.g. *.appdomain.com) for it, but I need to be sure ;-)

Has anyone tested this and can confirm that it is possible?

Comment: Hi @Tobias, I am also having same scenario where i need to change app domain because of corporate regulations(already used for SharePoint hosted add-in). Have you succeeded with it? What will be the impact on existing running provider hosted and sharepoint hosted add-ins if we reconfigure the app domain?